# Which of the following requests do not go through the Virtual File System (VFS) in Linux?

Tags: filesystems, vfs

I recently got the following question in a test.

Which of the following requests do not go through the Virtual File System (VFS) in Linux?

1. Reading/writing to a Windows partition from Linux
2. Reading the input
   of a keyboard
3. Sending output to a monitor
4. All of the above go
   through    VFS

What should be the answer to this question?
PS: This was asked in a 20 minutes quiz.

Answer (score 2):

2 and 3 don’t involve file systems so they don’t go through the VFS.

Comment: Indeed.  Recommended reading for the OP : https://tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/fs/vfstour.html and https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/vfs.html